# bnlearn setting and dropping arcs inplace

Tags: r, bnlearn

Looking at http://www.bnlearn.com/documentation/man/arcops.html, the way to drop arcs is to use the `drop.arcs` function.

It doesn't seem to be dropping it though

```
library(bnlearn)
data(learning.test)
res = gs(learning.test)

arcs(res)
     from to 
[1,] "A"  "B"
[2,] "A"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "E"
[5,] "C"  "D"
[6,] "F"  "E"

drop.arc(res, "A", "B")
arcs(res)
     from to 
[1,] "A"  "B"
[2,] "A"  "D"
[3,] "B"  "A"
[4,] "B"  "E"
[5,] "C"  "D"
[6,] "F"  "E"
```

But in the debug logs it seems like it worked.

```
drop.arc(res, "A","B",debug=T)
* dropping any arc between  A and B .
  > dropping any arc between A and B .
* (re)building cached information about node A.
* node A.
  > found child D.
  > found node C in markov blanket.
  > node A has 0 parent(s), 1 child(ren), 1 neighbour(s) and 2 nodes in the markov blanket.
...
```

Is this a problem with `R3.4.3` ? How to use arc operations while checking for cycles? I could always replace the `res$arcs` table, but I want to be able to check for cycles.

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree     
> packageVersion('bnlearn')
[1] '4.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

The help page for `?drop.arcs` says

> "All functions return invisibly an updated copy of x."

You have to assign the the results of the function call to an object. So try

```
res2 = drop.arc(res, "A", "B") 
arcs(res2)
```